# Limit a widget on an area

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I want to know if you can set a limit of a specific widget in an area.

I know that with the property "limit" you can limit all the widgets of an area, however, I could not implement to limit a specific widget.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Currently not a built-in way to limit the number of a specific widget type within an area. I can think of half-way workarounds but nothing that achieves all the flexibility an area-imposed limit would. It would be a good feature!